# Count the occurance of a field given a value of another field

Tags: bash, unix, design-patterns, scripting, awk

I have a tab delimited table like the one below

```
402 Tea Bags    4
403 Tea Bags    4
404 Tea Bags    3
405 Milk    3
406 Sugar   4
407 Sugar   3
408 Sugar   4
409 Milk    4
410 Milk    3
411 Milk    3
```

I want to calculate the occurrence of second field given the condition of third field. Example number of occurrence of Tea Bags when third field is 3 and 4.Like when

```
$3==4 && $2=="Tea Bags"; count ++
```

There can be more than two numbers in the third field and more than 3 options in second column.

And then I want to finally list them as

```
Tea Bags    4  2
Tea Bags    3  1
Milk    3  3
Milk    4  1
Sugar   4  2
Sugar   3  1
```

I can individually calculate them in awk using

```
awk -F "\t" '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) 
    if(($i=="Tea Bags" && ($(i+1)==3))) c++ } 
   END{ print c }' file.txt
```

However, I guess there should be a shorter and efficient way to do this as I have a very large file. Thanks!!

Comment: When you say `There can be more than two numbers in the third field and more than 3 options in second column.` you mean there are more possibilities for the second field than the three (Milk, Tea Bags and Sugar) that you've shown and similarly that there are more than two possibilities for the third column than the two (3 and 4) that you have shown?

Comment: Number of options in second field is never greater than the third.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about this awk one-liner:

```
 awk '{sub(/\S*\t/,"");a[$0]++}END{for(x in a)print x, a[x]}' file
```

Comment: Thanks but how can I arrange such that two Milk come together. Next item is started only after first item's count is complete?

Comment: @lovedynasty the easiest way is pipe the output to `sort`

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you want?

```
BEGIN {FS="\t"; OFS="\t"}

{a[$2,$3]++}

END {
    for (k in a) {
        split(k, p, SUBSEP)
        print p[1], p[2], a[k]
    }
}
```

alternatively written (to avoid split/SUBSEP)

```
BEGIN {FS="\t"; OFS="\t"}

{a[$2 OFS $3]++}

END {
    for (k in a) {
        print k, a[k]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using this awk command:

```
awk -F "\t" '{k=$2 FS $3; if (!(k in a)) s[j++]=k; a[k]++} 
             END {for (i=0; i<length(s); i++) print s[i], a[s[i]]}' OFS="\t" file

Tea Bags        4       2
Tea Bags        3       1
Milk    3       3
Sugar   4       2
Sugar   3       1
Milk    4       1
```

Answer (score 0):

A Bash solution using an associative array:

```
declare -A count

while IFS=$'\t'; read col1 col23 ; do
  ((count[$col23]++))                 # use col 2 and 3 as key
done < "$infile"

for key in "${!count[@]}"; do
  echo -e "$key\t${count[$key]}"
done
```

The output:

```
Tea Bags    4   2
Tea Bags    3   1
Sugar   4   2
Sugar   3   1
Milk    4   1
Milk    3   3
```